# After installing Eclipse and I get a "Please ensure that WebKit with its GTK 3.x bindings is installed" error when running it

Tags: gtk, gtk3, eclipse, webkit

On RHEL 8 I just installed Eclipse 2021-09 from the standalone install archive `eclipse-jee-2021-09-R-linux-gtk-x86_64.tar.gz`.

When running it, the application opens up with the default window, but then shows an error dialog with the following message:

> Unhandled event loop exception
> No more handles because there is no underlying browser available.
> Please ensure that WebKit with its GTK 3.x bindings is installed (WebKit2 API level is preferred). Additionally, please note that GTK4 does not currently have Browser support.

I guess some libraries are missing. For another X11 application I had already run `yum install gtk3-devel gtk2-devel` but Eclipse might need more.

What do I have install to get Eclipse running?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Going by the error message, I suspect you need to install `webkit2gtk3`:

```
sudo dnf install webkit2gtk3
```

Comment: That was it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case you come up here from Google search and use `yay`, then you need to install `webkit2gtk` from `extra/webkit2gtk`:

```
yay webkit2gtk
```